# Elastic user password is not working for my docker image

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

When I am using the elasticsearch official docker image ELASTIC_PASSWORD env variable is working good

```
docker run -dti -e ELASTIC_PASSWORD=my_own_password  -e discovery.type=single-node elasticsearch:7.8.0
```

But when I build my own customized docker image the ELASTIC_PASSWORD is not working can you please help me on this

Here is my Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV \
 REFRESHED_AT=2020-06-20


###############################################################################
#                                INSTALLATION
###############################################################################

### install prerequisites (cURL, gosu, tzdata, JDK for Logstash)

RUN set -x \
 && apt update -qq \
 && apt install -qqy --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl gosu tzdata openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
 && apt clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && gosu nobody true \
 && set +x






### set current package version

ARG ELK_VERSION=7.8.0


### install Elasticsearch

# predefine env vars, as you can't define an env var that references another one in the same block
ENV \
 ES_VERSION=${ELK_VERSION} \
 ES_HOME=/opt/elasticsearch

ENV \
 ES_PACKAGE=elasticsearch-${ES_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
 ES_GID=991 \
 ES_UID=991 \
 ES_PATH_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch \
 ES_PATH_BACKUP=/var/backups \
 KIBANA_VERSION=${ELK_VERSION}

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
 && mkdir ${ES_HOME} \
 && curl -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/${ES_PACKAGE} \
 && tar xzf ${ES_PACKAGE} -C ${ES_HOME} --strip-components=1 \
 && rm -f ${ES_PACKAGE} \
 && groupadd -r elasticsearch -g ${ES_GID} \
 && useradd -r -s /usr/sbin/nologin -M -c "Elasticsearch service user" -u ${ES_UID} -g elasticsearch elasticsearch \
 && mkdir -p /var/log/elasticsearch ${ES_PATH_CONF} ${ES_PATH_CONF}/scripts /var/lib/elasticsearch ${ES_PATH_BACKUP}
```

Comment: Why you are not using or extending official image?

Comment: @Adiii want to build docker image logstash, elasticsearch & kibana single docker image. That's why I am trying to build customized image

Comment: so extend the elastic search image and install rest of the two

Comment: can't do that, elastic base image will not work for me

Comment: Docker is designed to execute a single process per container. You should use docker-compose and define a container for each application. When you modify the official image, you should post your code and describe what exactly _doesnt work for you_.

Answer (score 0):

As I think in order to achieve this functionality (set `ELASTIC_PASSWORD` from command line and it works) for your own container you need to re-configure Elasticsearch startup script. It's not a trivial task.

For example here is `docker-entrypoint.sh` from official docker image.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/docker/src/docker/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
You can see that script do all 'hidden' work to allow us to run it by only command.